# How to assign a JSON object to a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a JSON file that contains:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "ProductOne",
    "Price": 10,
    "Year": 1990,
    "#": 2
  },
  {
    "Name": "ProductTwo",
    "Price": 12,
    "Year": 2000,
    "#": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "ProductThree",
    "Price": 5,
    "Year": 2014,
    "#": 6
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to use the information from the json to fill into the var product = {}, and fill the:

```
product.name
product.price
product.year
product.number
```

based on what option they select in the drop down menu on the index page.
Right now I hard coded the product information into the switch case statements, but I know that would not be the best.

I was wondering how I can the values from the JSON and insert them under the switch case statements, based on what the user selects from the drop down menu?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Product Select</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <select name="productList" id="selectedProduct" onchange="productInfo();" >
            <option disabled selected value>Select Item</option>
            <option id="product1" value="product1">Product1</option>
            <option id="product2" value="product2">Product2</option>
            <option id="product3" value="product3">Product3</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="reset()">Reload page</button>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var product = {};
product.name = null;
product.price = 0;
product.year = 0;
product.number = 0;

// Create a variable with the url to the JSON file
var url"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jakesterne/e9927b4dfb4ee94717e9fcd7530f33a7/raw/3156be812bbf0decf7f4448d82f6e2f298e95d24/product.json";

var productArray = [];

// Load the json file
d3.json(url2, function(error, data) {
    // Output the first observation to the log
    //console.log(data);

    for(var i in data)
    productArray.push([i, data[i]]);

    console.log(productArray);
});

function produductInfo() {
var productSelection = document.getElementById("selectedProduct");
    var productOption = productSelection.options[productSelection.selectedIndex].value;

    var product1 = document.getElementById("product1").value;
    var product2 = document.getElementById("product2").value;
    var product3 = document.getElementById("product3").value;

    switch (productOption) {
      case "product1":
          product.name = "ProductOne";
          product.price = 10.00;
          product.year = 1990;
          product.number = 2;
        break;

      case "product2":
             ...
        break;

      case "product3":
             ...
        break;

      default:
         product.name = null;
         product.price = 0;
         product.year = 0;
         product.number = 0;      
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  If you're throwing out and ignoring all that data you're bringing by overwriting it, why bring it in at all?  What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: @Brad With just three products, I wouldn't mind hard coding in the data, but I want to know how I would go about when I have to incorporate a large amount of data, like 50+ products.

Comment: Sure, but then why would you want this switch/case?  There's no reason for that.  Your question asks about assigning data, but you probably don't want to assign anything... you just need to read from the product, right?  If so, just set the option value to be the index of the product in your array and go from there.

Comment: @Brad I need to assign the product information because the visualization I'm trying to do changes based on the values of the year and number of the chosen product.

Comment: You don't need a switch/case for that though... that's the opposite of what you want.  And, you certainly don't want to be changing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want these two things :

- Bind `json` data to `ng-repeat` to show the select options from the JSON.
- On `select` you want to get whole object of the `selected` item.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.jsonObj = [
  {
    "Name": "ProductOne",
    "Price": 10,
    "Year": 1990,
    "#": 2
  },
  {
    "Name": "ProductTwo",
    "Price": 12,
    "Year": 2000,
    "#": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "ProductThree",
    "Price": 5,
    "Year": 2014,
    "#": 6
  }
];

$scope.selectedProduct = function(product) {
  var result = $scope.jsonObj.filter(item => { return item['#'] == product; });
  console.log(result[0]);
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="item['#'] as item.Name for item in jsonObj" ng-model="product" ng-change="selectedProduct(product)"></select>
</div>
```